# Why am I getting an error while working with two datasources in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC with Hibernate.  I'm trying to use two different databases (on two different servers).  One is MySQL and the other is DB2.

Here is my dispatcher-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Load JDBC Properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- Enable Annotations (MVC and Hibernate Transactions) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Tell Spring where to find static files and not use a controller -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/css/*" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/WEB-INF/js/*" />

    <!-- Create a ViewResolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Create a DataSource for MySQL -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${mysql.database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${mysql.database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${mysql.database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${mysql.database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Create a DataSource for DB2 -->
    <bean id="db2DataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db2.database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db2.database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db2.database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db2.database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Create a Session Factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.example.model.entities.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${mysql.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${mysql.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${mysql.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactoryDB2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="db2DataSource" ref="db2DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.example.model.entities.Transfer</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db2.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db2.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${db2.hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${db2.hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${db2.hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${db2.hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${db2.hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <!-- Create a Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionFactoryDB2" ref="sessionFactoryDB2" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But when I run I get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transfersController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.example.model.service.UserService....
```

I am using @Autowired in my controllers/models.  So it makes sense that it doesn't know which bean to use to autowire.  But how do I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Post the full error message. The key part that tells you the real error is usually towards the end. Without this, no one can help you. The XML snippet you've posted shows nothing to do with your `UserService`.

Comment: do you use annotation(`@Service`) for `UserService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <bean id="sessionFactoryDB2" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="db2DataSource" ref="db2DataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
```

I don't think there is a property named `db2DataSource` in `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. That may be one of the reason it is failing. It should be `<property name="dataSource" ref="db2DataSource" />` instead.

Comment: This was actually the solution.  I didn't really understand how that session factory bean was being initialized.  In the bean, there is a property called "dataSource".  So by setting the ref to my second datasource, that solved it.  Makes sense now that I look it over again!

Answer (score 1):

I think problem does not exist with your dataSources. To autowire service classes you need to use `@Service`(preferred for service layer classes) stereotype annotation.

You also need to scan these annotated classes using component scan which I didn't see in your posted xml.

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.example, com.example.model.service" />
```